# Why typedef a class as a pointer in c++

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-construction

Can anyone help me understand the following typedef ( a part of the auto-generated code to represent the Abstract Syntax Tree of a compiler)? How am I supposed to use Class_?
Why was Class__class typedef'ed this way?

```
// define simple phylum - Class_
typedef class Class__class *Class_;

class Class__class : public tree_node {
public:
   tree_node *copy()         { return copy_Class_(); }
   virtual Class_ copy_Class_() = 0;

#ifdef Class__EXTRAS
   Class__EXTRAS
#endif
};
```

Comment: I think you should as the one who wrote this

Comment: @Jorengarenar No. It is part of the abstract syntax tree of a compiler. What leads you to believe it is my code?

Comment: What leads you believe I was refering to you when I said "_the one who wrote this_"?

Answer (score 2):

It defines the type `Class_` as a pointer to the `class Class__class`.

This is used as the return type in the following declaration of the virtual method `copy_Class_()`.